# lvalue required as left operand of assignment error via if statement

Tags: c++

I've looked at similar questions, but being a total newbie at this, they haven't helped much, when I try to run my final if statement I run into this error, how can I make my cout statement clearer? Its intended purpose is to output how many bags of garbage it can accept, how many the user is trying to give it, and how many bags will be left over if it cannot take them all.

```
while(( reg < 50) && (met< 20) && (glass < 20))
{
reg=reg+reg; met=met+met; glass=glass+glass;
cout<< " I have enough "<< endl;


if(reg+=reg > 50){
cout<< "I can only accept " << 50 - (reg+=reg) << "of your " << (reg+=reg)<<" regular     bags of garbage, I'll leave the other " << 50 - (reg+= reg)<< " I'll leave the other " << reg- (50 - reg+=reg)<< endl;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Using the assignment operator (and multiple times at that) in a statement is not really good style. In the case of multiple assignments I don't think behavior is defined if it's even allowed.

Comment: Can you describe what the code is supposed to do? I'm sure you don't want to keep doubling the value of `reg` each time you print something (which is what all those `reg+=reg` expressions do); but it's difficult to work out what it's supposed to be testing and printing.

Comment: I just figured out what I had initially been doing wrong, I had repeated a line of code twice, silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
50 - reg += reg;
```

`operator+=` has lower precedence than `operator-`. The above statement is interpreted as:

```
(50 - reg) += reg;
```

which won't work. You probably wanted:

```
50 - (reg += reg);
```